# Logstash Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action:

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, elk, docker-desktop

I started learning ELK and was trying to setup ELK locally on my docker desktop.This process works fine in Windows if I run the services separately. But if I run the services on docker I get error.

My elastic-search and kibana are working fine.

Docker command

```
docker run  -it --name=logstash --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch -v D:/logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.1
```

logstash.conf file

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/logs/service.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

output {
  
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "logs-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I get following error

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby10434374664132949646jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-09-24T03:57:01,161][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-LTS on 11.0.8+10-LTS +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:01,210][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:01,227][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:01,597][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"975ca258-9df4-4e76-a40b-8ba27de762e7", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:02,186][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
[2020-09-24T03:57:02,191][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,038][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,226][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,275][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,281][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,441][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
[2020-09-24T03:57:03,442][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,116][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 35 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 22 keys and 45 values
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,466][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,492][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,507][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,509][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,611][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchMonitoring", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,641][WARN ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] 'pipeline.ordered' is enabled and is likely less efficient, consider disabling if preserving event order is not necessary
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,750][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,757][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,767][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,768][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,792][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7f619e13 run>"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,805][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,827][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,835][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>3, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>375, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5094c85b run>"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:05,882][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2020-09-24T03:57:06,588][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.79}
[2020-09-24T03:57:06,648][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.81}
[2020-09-24T03:57:06,664][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:07,847][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2020-09-24T03:57:08,054][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-09-24T03:57:10,001][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2020-09-24T03:57:10,047][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

If I use logstash.conf file as

```
input {
 stdin {}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
}
```

Then logstash starts perfectly and the logs start coming in kibana.